# Unable to send data over windows UDP sockets:Error Code 10035

Tags: c++, sockets

I am trying to receive data on a program from another program running on the same windows 7 pc through sockets. For this i have made two separate program, one for sending and other for receiving.Send program is showing success but receive program is waiting indefinitely.when i put the receive socket in non blocking mode i am receiving error code 10035 ie resource unavailable. Is there any system setting i have to do like firewall or any thing. Although after disabling firewall i am getting same error.I searched the stackoverflow.com but could not get solution to my problem. 
I am giving the code below for send and receive functions.
**For Send Function:**

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#ifndef UNICODE
#define UNICODE
#endif
#define WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN
#include <winsock2.h>
#include <Ws2tcpip.h>
#include <stdio.h>
// Link with ws2_32.lib
#pragma comment(lib, "Ws2_32.lib")
using namespace System;
int main(array<System::String ^> ^args)
{   
    char ch;
    int iRun =1;
    int iResult;
    WSADATA wsaData;
    SOCKET SendSocket = INVALID_SOCKET;
    sockaddr_in RecvAddr;
    unsigned short Port = 51234;
    char SendBuf[1024]="Testing";
    int BufLen = 1024;
    //----------------------
    // Initialize Winsock
    iResult = WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2, 2), &wsaData);
    if (iResult != NO_ERROR) {
        wprintf(L"WSAStartup failed with error: %d\n", iResult);
        return 1;
    }
    //---------------------------------------------
    // Create a socket for sending data
    SendSocket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, IPPROTO_UDP);
    if (SendSocket == INVALID_SOCKET) {
        wprintf(L"socket failed with error: %ld\n", WSAGetLastError());
        WSACleanup();
        return 1;
    }
    //---------------------------------------------
    // Set up the RecvAddr structure with the IP address of
    // the receiver (in this example case "178.0.0.100")
    // and the specified port number.
    RecvAddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    RecvAddr.sin_port = htons(Port);
    RecvAddr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("178.0.0.100");
    //---------------------------------------------
    // Send a datagram to the receiver
    wprintf(L"Sending a datagram to the receiver...\n");
    while(iRun) {
        iResult = sendto(SendSocket,
                     SendBuf, BufLen, 0, (SOCKADDR *) & RecvAddr, sizeof (RecvAddr));
       if (iResult == SOCKET_ERROR) {
        wprintf(L"sendto failed with error: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
        //closesocket(SendSocket);
        //WSACleanup();
        //return 1;
    }
        wprintf(L"send success :data bytes: %d\n", iResult);
    } 
    //---------------------------------------------
    // When the application is finished sending, close the socket.
    wprintf(L"Finished sending. Closing socket.\n");
    iResult = closesocket(SendSocket);
    if (iResult == SOCKET_ERROR) {
        wprintf(L"closesocket failed with error: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
        WSACleanup();
        return 1;
    }
    //---------------------------------------------
    scanf("enter any number to terminate %c",&ch);
    // Clean up and quit.
    wprintf(L"Exiting.\n");
    WSACleanup();
    return 0;   
    //Console::WriteLine(L"Hello World");
    //return 0;
}
```

**For Receive Function**

```
#include "stdafx.h"    
#ifndef UNICODE
#define UNICODE
#endif    
#define WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN    
#include <winsock2.h>
#include <Ws2tcpip.h>
#include <stdio.h>    
// Link with ws2_32.lib
#pragma comment(lib, "Ws2_32.lib")    
using namespace System;    
int main(array<System::String ^> ^args)
{
    char ch;
    int iRun =1;
    int iResult = 0;    
    WSADATA wsaData;
    DWORD nonBlocking =1;    
    SOCKET RecvSocket;
    sockaddr_in RecvAddr;    
    unsigned short Port = 51234;    
    char RecvBuf[1024];
    int BufLen = 1024;    
    sockaddr_in SenderAddr;
    int SenderAddrSize = sizeof (SenderAddr);    
    //-----------------------------------------------
    // Initialize Winsock
    iResult = WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2, 2), &wsaData);
    if (iResult != NO_ERROR) {
        wprintf(L"WSAStartup failed with error %d\n", iResult);
        return 1;
    }
    //-----------------------------------------------
    // Create a receiver socket to receive datagrams
    RecvSocket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, IPPROTO_UDP);
    if (RecvSocket == INVALID_SOCKET) {
        wprintf(L"socket failed with error %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
        return 1;
    }
            // Setting socket to non blocking mode
    if(ioctlsocket(RecvSocket, FIONBIO, &nonBlocking)!= 0)
            printf("can't Set socket to non blocking mode \n");
    //-----------------------------------------------
    // Bind the socket to any address and the specified port.
    RecvAddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    RecvAddr.sin_port = htons(Port);
    RecvAddr.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);    
    iResult = bind(RecvSocket, (SOCKADDR *) & RecvAddr, sizeof (RecvAddr));
    if (iResult != 0) {
        wprintf(L"bind failed with error %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
        return 1;
    }
    //-----------------------------------------------
    // Call the recvfrom function to receive datagrams
    // on the bound socket.
    wprintf(L"Receiving datagrams...\n");
    while(iRun) {
    iResult = recvfrom(RecvSocket,
                       RecvBuf, BufLen, 0, (SOCKADDR *) & SenderAddr, &SenderAddrSize);
        if (iResult == SOCKET_ERROR) {
        wprintf(L"recvfrom failed with error %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
        Sleep(10);
        }
        //wprintf(L"recvfrom Success %d\n", iResult);
        //wprintf(L"Received Data %s \n",RecvBuf[BufLen]);
    }     
    //-----------------------------------------------
    // Close the socket when finished receiving datagrams
    wprintf(L"Finished receiving. Closing socket.\n");
    iResult = closesocket(RecvSocket);
    if (iResult == SOCKET_ERROR) {
        wprintf(L"closesocket failed with error %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
        return 1;
    }    
    //-----------------------------------------------
   scanf("enter any number to terminate %c",&ch);
    // Clean up and exit.
    wprintf(L"Exiting.\n");
    WSACleanup();
    return 0;

    //Console::WriteLine(L"Hello World");
    //return 0;
}
```

Can any one please help.

Regards

Mahendra

Comment: Is that IP address of the machine you are on? And what does your routing table look like?

Comment: Moreover. In the receiver you are binding to INADDR_ANY - that is not very deterministic. Probably you could try bind to the same address as your sender. If nothing just use loopback address see if it works.

Comment: Hi Nikolai yes that ip address is of my own pc.sorry but routing table i did not get.

Comment: Hi Nanda  what you are telling i have tried both that options but both are not working.

Comment: @nanda Binding to `0.0.0.0` is *completely* 'deterministic', and you can't 'bind to the same address as your sender'. What are you talking about?

Comment: @EJP In a multihomed host using INADDR_ANY can bind the socket to any of the available interfaces (there is more detail http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms737550%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). As the communication is happening within the machine using loopback with different port for sender and receiver could be tried too.

Answer (score 0):

Did you look it up? Winsock error code 10035 is `WSAEWOULDBLOCK`. You are in non-blocking mode, and the operation you are attempting cannot be completed, because either your send buffer is full when sending or your receive buffer is empty when receiving.

Comment: yes i am also thinking this is the problem...but how to solve this...i am working first time on socket programming..when i put receiving program in blocking mode receiving program is waiting indefinitely...

Comment: @MAHENDRAKUMAR Why are you using non-blocking mode at all if you don't know what you're going to do when operations would have blocked in blocking mode? Just *use* blocking mode.